# ZeroMQ Dealer to Dealer - work distribution

Tags: message-queue, zeromq, distributed-computing

Consider the following setup. I `connect()` multiple `DEALER` sockets (clients) to another `DEALER`, bound to an address (server). Exactly one of the clients calls **`recv()`** in a loop, while the other clients may occasionaly send something to the server.

Will the server socket try to distribute sent messages to those clients that don't receive anything? I couldn't find how exactly dealer sockets deal with work distribution in the ZeroMQ Guide nor in the `zmq_socket` manpage.

I use ZMQ 4.1.

Comment: The tail remark "nor in the `zmq_socket` manpage" is not fair. The manpage defines `DEALER`-side behaviour and it is to be understood in the distributed processing context. The local end "behavioural primitive" does not perform remote-end handshaked flow-control due to many reasons. If in such a need, software architects can create additional abstractions and signalling layers with respect to their individual needs for adding mutual handshaking **( where the `O(1)` scaleability, latency envelope and resources-conservation is the ultimate target for any such add-on effort )**

Comment: I said I couldn't find it, now I see and understand it :)

Comment: You could potentially take a different approach and make your server a [router socket](http://api.zeromq.org/4-1:zmq-socket#toc7).  Using the ids that are inherent to the router socket, you could then take full control over where the server sends messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Not all versions of ZeroMQ work the same way

The safe way is to check the respective version **`API man-page`** for details. Not all projects may use the latest API, due to interoperability reasons when any of the counterparties simply does not have any newer version API binding available. Then the oldest one rulez the crowd.

`ZeroMQ 2.1.11 API` does not permit `DEALER/DEALER`
`ZeroMQ 4.2.0  API` does

In any case, [**`API man-pages`**](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-socket) are always a worth source of details:

> <sup>4.2.0</sup>
> **`ZMQ_DEALER`**
> A socket of type `ZMQ_DEALER` is an advanced pattern used for extending request/reply sockets. Each message sent is round-robined among all connected peers, and each message received is fair-queued from all connected peers.
> When a `ZMQ_DEALER` socket enters the mute state due to having reached the high water mark for all peers, or if there are no peers at all, then any `zmq_send(3)` operations on the socket shall block until the mute state ends or at least one peer becomes available for sending; messages are not discarded.
>   When a `ZMQ_DEALER` socket is connected to a `ZMQ_REP` socket each message sent must consist of an empty message part, the delimiter, followed by one or more body parts.
> **Summary of `ZMQ_DEALER` characteristics**

```
Compatible peer sockets:      ZMQ_ROUTER, ZMQ_REP, ZMQ_DEALER
Direction:                    Bidirectional
Send/receive pattern:         Unrestricted
Outgoing routing strategy:    Round-robin
Incoming routing strategy:    Fair-queued
Action in mute state:         Block
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't really answer my question, which was whether the dealer tries to send messages to peers that don't call recv(). I should have said that I'm interested in the 4.x version and that I read the manpage you refenced, though.

Comment: Well, actually the manpage does say that messages are round-robined among all connected peers. I guess I just expected ZMQ to be a bit smarter...

Comment: The third row from bottom **exactly explains this very nature of the  `DEALER` design.** The answer does not deserve your objection.

Comment: After many years in ZeroMQ domain, I would dare to say it is not smart or to export my responsibility onto ZMQ side and wish if it were smarter. The **S**caleable **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**atterns are primitives of behaviour, whereas the software architect is responsible in their proper re-use and combinations. The ability to behave in **both a predictable and scaleable** manner is the greatest power we get from the toolbox. Anyone can add additional layers of signalling to detect/differ among "receiving" and "inactive" peers & use other than blind-belief round-robin distribution rules

Comment: You're right, it doesn't, though it could have contained something like "TL;DR: No." :) Accepting your answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little test program and found out that the dealer socket doesn't know if the other end is receiving. Therefore, it tries to distribute outgoing messages to all of the connected peers.